# Can this derivative be equal to zero?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let

$$I= \int_ 1^n (t-[t])(st^{s-2} - (1-s)t^{-s-1}) \mathrm {d}t,$$

where $s \in \mathbb {C}$. Is it possible that $\dfrac{dI}{ds} = 0$ ?

Comment: Have you [b]calculated[/b] dI/ds?  It not at all hard.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{dI}{ds}=0$ for *some* or for *all* $s$?

Answer (score 2):

In a complex domain, we also have that if $\frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}s}$ is constant is zero, then $I$ is constant in $s$.

Let $s=0$, then we get $$I(0)= \int_1^n (t-[t])\cdot -t^{-1} \mathrm{d}t$$

Let $s=2$, then we get $$I(2)= \int_1^n (t-[t])(2+t^{-3}) \mathrm{d}t$$

Note that the real part of the first integral is negative since $t-[t]>0$ for real $t>0$ and $-t^{-1}<0$ for real $t>0$. However, the real part of the second integral is positive since $t-[t]>0$ for real $t>0$ and $2+t^{-3}>0$ for real $t>0$.

Hence they can't be equal. Hence the function is not constant, and hence the derivative is not everywhere equal to zero.